# JMS Serializer ignoring non-persisted property

Tags: json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I've been struggling with a property on one of my Symfony2/Doctrine objects that isn't persisted in the database. It's an array of objects that contain properties like label, key and value, but even if it is defined as a simple array of arrays, it doesn't show up.

Here is the way that the array is defined in the object that is normally persisted:

```
/*
* @Accessor(getter="getReceipt",setter="setReceipt")
* @Type("ArrayCollection<MyProject\ReceiptProperty>")
* @Expose
* @Groups({"details"})
*/
protected $receipt;

public function setReceipt($receipt) {
    $this->receipt = $receipt;
}

public function getReceipt() {
    return $this->receipt;
}
```

And here is how the object in the array is defined

```
/**
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class ReceiptProperty extends APIObject {
    /**
    * @Type("string")
    * @Expose
    * @Groups({"basic"})
    */
    public $label;

    /**
    * @Type("string")
    * @Expose
    * @Groups({"basic"})
    */
    public $type;

    /**
    * @Type("string")
    * @Expose
    * @Groups({"basic"})
    */
    public $key;

    /**
    * @Expose
    * @Groups({"basic"})
    */
    public $value;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->label = $data['label'];
        $this->type = $data['type'];
        $this->key = $data['key'];
        $this->value = $data['value'];
    }
}
```

By straight printing the objects before going into serialization with print_r, I can see that the data is there, but no matter what the configuration is, that field is never shown.

Comment: You might need to use @VirtualProperty given it's a non persisted property. http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations

Answer (score 2):

In an effort to help those that might have similar issues going forward, my problem was essentially an incorrect annotation.

In the first code block you'll notice that the annotation comment begins with /*

It turns out that JMS Serializer does not process comments that do not start with /** so effectively it was ignoring my commands. After updating the annotation comment, it worked as expected. It's always the little things...